# Explaining a concept from a line of code in C#

Tags: c#

I am an absolute beginner in C# but I had a prior contact with C++ simply and JavaScript. Anyway, I would like to ask about a line of code:
*private enum States {....};*

I want to know more what does this line of code does.

Also, this line :
*private States mystate;*

I know that this line initializes a variable *mystate* that is given a type *States*. So what is the States type have to do if it is really a type?? And what does it have to do with the first mentioned line of code as both lines are present in the same script.

Sorry for elongation but I am really confused and stuck there although I know it may be a trivial issue.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. But this may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: `private enum States {....};` defines the enum and it's values. 
`private States mystate;` is an instance of that enum. if you write `mystate.` a set of option will appear to you that include the enum options.

Comment: Alright ... So the second line must always be there after any enum or is it optional ??

Comment: no. it's not a must. you should read more about it instead of asking, because this is not something unique to enums. it's the same for class\struct definition and creating a instances of that class\enum.

Comment: Ok many thanks ... I got now but still I will try to dive more in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private enum States {....};` is the definition of the enum. It lists out all of the possible values which the creator intends the enum to have.

`private States mystate;` is a declaration of a class-level variable whose type is `States`, i.e. the enum. `States` in this usage is only to tell you (and the compiler) that the variable should hold enum values that are defined by the `States` enum.

Answer (score 2):

Your first line:

```
private enum States {....};
```

declares an [enumerated type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx), specifically one that enumerates a set of states.

Your second line:

```
private States mystate;
```

delcares a variable `mystate` having that (enumerated) type, with `private` [accessibility level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).